# Spring Batch: How to exit job skipping steps based on condition

Tags: spring-batch

Consider the steps (A,B,C,D,E) in a Spring Batch Job.

Based on a condition check fail in Step A, the job should be assumed as complete skipping B,C,D,E. If the condition check is successful, steps B,C,D,E should be executed normally.

How do we configure the job in such a scenario? What could be used to decide the flow?

**Note:** Checked JobExecutionDecider. I would like to know if it's the right approach to this scenario or is there a better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in the Spring Batch reference [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#endElement).

What you need to do is make your step return a custom `ExitStatus` and configure this step to end the job when this exit status is returned.

Comment: Thanks Tunaki. "Configure this step to end the job when this exit status is returned." - how can this be done in the above mentioned case?

Comment: Using the `<end>` element mentioned in the reference. If your tasklet return the ExitStatus FAILED, then you can write in the config of your step `<end on="FAILED"/>`.